# Which one preg_match pattern will be right to check identificator?

Tags: php, regex

Have a small trouble with a right preg_match pattern to check identificators like below:

```
WDL-86125858
SNH-12361400
VZB-46756554
```

Need to check it have 3 letters (A-Z), then dash, and then 8 numbers (0-9). Anyone can help?

Comment: `^[A-Z]{3}-[\d]{8}$` use this one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `^[A-Z]{3}-[0-9]{8}$`